# Node.js TCP forwarder

Tags: tcp, node.js

I have the following simple NodeJS script and want to modify it slightly....

```
var sys = require( 'sys' ), net = require( 'net' );

var outputserver = net.createServer( function( stream ) {
    stream.addListener( 'data', function( data ) {
        sys.puts( data );
        //Want to output anything from the clientserver data here
    });
}).listen( 7001, 'localhost' );

var clientserver = net.createServer( function( stream ) {
    stream.addListener( 'data', function( data ) {
        sys.puts( data );

    });
}).listen( 7000, 'localhost' );
```

I need anything coming in from the "clientserver" to be output to the "outputserver" stream.  There will be 50-60 clients connecting to the the "clientserver"

Comment: More food for thought: Naively piping streams from several client TCP connections may easily break. As an example, an HTTP server may receive a full HTTP request in a single listener callback, but it may also receive it split in several callbacks. Imagine what the output server then receives when these chunks are mixed. You will want to add a bit of framing or application intelligence (e.g. buffer until you have full request) so you can properly 'multiplex'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
var util = require('util'), net = require('net');
var outServer = net.createServer(function(outStream) {
  outStream.on('data', function(data) {
    util.puts(data);
  });
  var inServer = net.createServer(function(inStream) {
    inStream.pipe(outStream, {end: false});
  });
  inServer.listen(7001, 'localhost');
});
outServer.listen(7000, 'localhost');
```

Comment: I think it's important to mention here that the server accepting input won't start listening until a connection is made to the output server. This is one way of solving the problem what to do when there is nothing to output to, or what to do if there are multiple outputs. (And also important, multiple output connections will cause this code to fail!) But that's all food for thought, and it's still a good answer.

Comment: @Shtééf: Thanks for your input. You are quite right - I just wanted to show a minimal way of solving the problem.